# Python script to highlight data mismatch from predefined list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a predefined list of **Service** and **CI** in Excel:

| Service | CI |
| --- | --- |
| Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa | Aravo |
| Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa | Business Resilience |
| Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa | Change Risk Management |
| First Line Control Attestation South Africa | Control First |
| Group Audit Assurance South Africa | DigiAud |
| Group Governance Advisory and Support South Africa | Diligent Boardbooks |

I get an extract of data from our call logging system which also has the Service and CI columns.
I need to highlight if the Service and CI in the call extract does not match the predefined list.

My code so far works for one **Service** in the predefined list, I need to figure out how to add the rest of the listed Services in my predefined list. IF I run it as is it works for the **Service** named **Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa** but highlights all the other Services in RED.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

extract = Path.cwd() / "/extract.xlsx"
df_extract = pd.read_excel(extract)


m = (df_extract['Service'] == 'Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa') & (df_extract['CI'].isin(['Aravo', 'Business Resilience', 'Change Risk Management']))


(df_extract.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(m, '', 'background-color: red'))
   .to_excel('/output.xlsx', index=False))
```

I tried adding a 2nd boolean mask but I cant figure out how to integrate with the np.where:

```
n = (df_extract['Service'] == 'First Line Control Attestation South Africa') & (df_extract['CI'].isin(['Control First']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need chain both masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
(df_extract.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(m | n, '', 'background-color: red'))
           .to_excel('/output.xlsx', index=False))
```

If there is more masks is possible create dictionary and pass to `mask` for more readable code:

```
#add more key:values if necessary
d = {'Non-Financial Risk Management South Africa':['Aravo', 'Business Resilience',
                                                   'Change Risk Management'],
     'First Line Control Attestation South Africa':['Control First']}

mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df_extract['Service'].eq(k) &  df_extract['CI'].isin(v)  
                             for k, v in d.items()])

(df_extract.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(mask, '', 'background-color: red'))
           .to_excel('/output.xlsx', index=False))
```